# How can I get rid of this data race

Tags: go

I have these 2 functions:

```
// PartyHub struct contains all data for the party
type PartyHub struct {
    FullPartys    map[string]Party
    PartialPartys map[string]Party
    Enter         chan Member
    Leave         chan Member
    sync.Mutex
}


// RemoveFromQueue will remove the member from party
func (p *PartyHub) RemoveFromQueue(memberLeaving Member, inQueue bool) {
    if !inQueue {
        return
    }
    for _, party := range p.PartialPartys {
        go func(party Party) {
            if _, ok := party.Members[memberLeaving.Identifier]; ok {
                p.Lock()
->>>>>>>>       delete(party.Members, memberLeaving.Identifier)
                p.Unlock()
            }
        }(party)
    }
    log.Println("Removing")
}

// SortIntoParty will sort the member into party
func (p *PartyHub) SortIntoParty(newMember Member, inQueue bool) {
    log.Println(inQueue)
    if inQueue {
        return
    }
    log.Println("Adding")
    foundParty := false
->> for partyid, party := range p.PartialPartys {
        if !party.Accepting {
            continue
        }

        goodFitForParty := true
        for _, partyMember := range party.Members {
            if newMember.Type == partyMember.Type && newMember.Rank >= partyMember.Rank-partyMember.RankTol && newMember.Rank <= partyMember.Rank+partyMember.RankTol {
                goodFitForParty = true
                continue
            } else {
                goodFitForParty = false
                break
            }
        }

        if !goodFitForParty {
            continue
        } else {
            foundParty = true
            newMember.Conn.CurrentParty = partyid
            p.Lock()
            p.PartialPartys[partyid].Members[newMember.Conn.Identifier] = newMember
            p.Unlock()
            if len(party.Members) == 2 {
                p.Lock()
                party.Accepting = false
                p.Unlock()
                // Start Go Routine
            }
            break
        }
    }
    if !foundParty {
        uuid := feeds.NewUUID().String()
        newMember.Conn.CurrentParty = uuid
        p.Lock()
        p.PartialPartys[uuid] = Party{Accepting: true, Members: make(map[string]Member), Ready: make(chan *Connection), Decline: make(chan *Connection)}
        p.PartialPartys[uuid].Members[newMember.Conn.Identifier] = newMember
        p.Unlock()
    }
}
```

I put `->>>>>>` next to where the 2 pieces of code are being accessed, I'm not sure how I can keep these 2 up to date without being in a data race, fairly new to go and wondering how I should be reading and writing this variable without a data-race.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lot of code in your question, but it looks like you're trying to delete elements from a map (`party.Members`) in one goroutine, while looping over it in another. This sounds like an unmaintainable, error-ridden disaster in the making, but it's possible to do without memory races.

You need a mutex to protect access (both read and write) to the map, and the hard part is to make sure the lock is held during the `for/range` iteration. Here's one way to do it, by having the lock held before the `for` loop starts, and unlocking it inside the body of the loop.

```
var mut sync.Mutex
var m = map[string]int{}

func f(key string) {
    mut.Lock()
    defer mut.Unlock()
    delete(m, key)
}

func g() {
    mut.Lock()
    defer mut.Unlock()
    for k, v := range m {
        mut.Unlock()
        fmt.Println(k, v)
        mut.Lock()
    }
}
```

Here, any combination of `f`s and `g`s can be called concurrently without memory races.

Drastically simpler to understand would be to not Unlock/Lock the mutex inside the loop, which would mean a deletion in `f` would wait for any running loop in `g` to complete (or vice-versa).

Comment: Actually, your `g` is a deadlock, you're locking in side the loop and outside.

Comment: @OneOfOne I don't think so: inside the loop the mutex is unlocked first and locked second.